# Validate multiple models in single Form

Tags: cakephp

I have to validate multiple model in single form using 'CakePHP'.
I have 2 models.

**Invoice**

```
public $validate = array(
        'type' => array(
            'rule' =>'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Select Invoice Type.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'number' => array(
            'rule' =>'numeric',
            'message' => 'Enter Invoice Number.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array('date', 'dmy'),
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Enter Invoice Date.'
        ),
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
        ));
```

**Client**

```
public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' =>'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Enter Your Name.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'company' => array(
            'rule' =>'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Enter Your Company Name.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'address' => array(
            'rule' =>'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Enter Your address.',
            'required' => true
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = 'Invoice';
```

And I have one form with Fields like '*clientName*', '*Address*', '*InvoiceNumber*' and '*InvoiceDate*'.
I have used saveAll(), but it is only validating `Invoice` data and not the `Client` data.

Comment: Please show us how you are creating the Form.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673403/1110760

> hasMany model's fields should be as array (when combined with parent model), see .0 added between field names

If you would like to post your Form as well when you are still stuck, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

taken from here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

```
if ($this->ModelName->saveAll(
    $this->request->data, array('validate' => 'only')
)) {
  // validates
} else {
  // does not validate
}
```