# CakePHP: Validating one form with 2 unrelated models

Tags: validation, cakephp

When trying to validate a form with 2 unrelated models, validation errors don't show up for on of the models i.e. the Customer Model.

**Partial View:**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top" width="175">Username:</td>
  <td><?php echo $form->input('Customer.username', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top" width="175">Email Address:</td>
  <td><?php echo $form->input('Customer.email', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top" width="175">First Name:</td>
  <td><?php echo $form->input('billing_firstname', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top">Last Name:</td>
  <td><?php echo $form->input('billing_lastname', array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><?php echo $form->button('>> Verify Order'); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Customer Model:**

```
<?php
class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Customer';
    var $validate = array('username' => array(array('rule'=>'notEmpty'),
                                              array('rule'=>'/.*[a-z]+.*/i', 'message'=>'Your username must have at least one letter in it'),
                                              array('rule'=>'isUnique', 'message'=>'Username already exists')),
                          'email'  => array('between' => array('rule' => array('between', 5, 50), 'message' => 'Between 5 to 50 characters'),
                                            'email' => array('rule' => 'email', 'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address'),
                                            'identicalFieldValues' => array('rule' => array('identicalFieldValues','vemail'), 'message' => 'Both email addresses must match')));
    // validation rule
    function identicalFieldValues( $field=array(), $compare_field=null )
    {
        foreach( $field as $key => $value ){
            $v1 = $value;
            $v2 = $this->data[$this->name][ $compare_field ];
            if($v1 !== $v2) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```

**Checkout Information Model:**

```
<?php
class CheckoutInformation extends Model {
    var $useTable = false;


    var $validate = array('billing_firstname'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'billing_lastname'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'billing_address1'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'billing_city'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'billing_state'  => array(array('rule'=>array('minLength', 2)),
                                            array('rule'=>array('maxLength',2))),
                          'billing_zip'  => array(array('rule'=> array('between', 5, 5), 'message'=>'Zip must be 5 digits'),
                                            array('rule'=> 'numeric', 'message'=>'Zip must be 5 digits')),
                          'shipping_firstname'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'shipping_lastname'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'shipping_address1'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'shipping_city'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'shipping_state'  => array(array('rule'=>array('minLength', 2)),
                                            array('rule'=>array('maxLength',2))),
                          'shipping_zip'  => array(array('rule'=> array('between', 5, 5), 'message'=>'Zip must be 5 digits'),
                                            array('rule'=> 'numeric', 'message'=>'Zip must be 5 digits')),
                          'username' => array(array('rule'=>'notEmpty'),
                                              array('rule'=>'/.*[a-z]+.*/i',
                                                    'message'=>'Your username must have at least one letter in it')),


                          'email'  => array(

                                                        'email' => array('rule' => 'email',

                                                                         'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address')

                                             ),
                          'password'  => array('identicalFieldValues' => array('rule' => array('identicalFieldValues','vpassword' ), 'message' => 'Both passwords must match'),
                                                        'between' => array('rule' => array('between', 6,12),
                                                                           'message' => 'Between 6 - 12 characters')),
                          //'member_number'  => 'notEmpty',
                          'cc_type' => 'notEmpty',
                          'cc_holder' => 'notEmpty',
                          'cc_num' => array('rule' => array('cc', 'fast', false, null),
                                            'message' => 'The credit card number you supplied was invalid.'),
                          'cc_exp_mon' => 'numeric',
                          'cc_exp_year' => 'numeric',
                          'cc_cvc' => 'numeric',
                          'ba_name' => 'notEmpty',
                          'ba_type' => array('rule' => array('inList', array('Foo', 'Bar')),
                                             'message' => 'Please select the type of bank account.'),
                          'ba_bank_name' => 'notEmpty',
                          'ba_account_number' => array(array('rule'=>'notEmpty'),
                                                       array('rule'=>array('between', 9,15))),
                          'ba_routing' => array(array('rule' => 'notEmpty'),
                                                array('rule' => array('between', 9, 15))));


    // validation rule
  function identicalFieldValues( $field=array(), $compare_field=null )
    {
        foreach( $field as $key => $value ){
            $v1 = $value;
            $v2 = $this->data[$this->name][ $compare_field ];
            if($v1 !== $v2) {
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775385/82135 is correct. As my models are not related, the answer marked as correct on that question did not work for me.